# How do I Insert 2 button in every row of data in the datagridview in VB.net getting its data from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have this code:

```
Public Sub LoadDataAS()
    txtSearchBar1.Clear()
    mycom.Connection = cn
    mycom.CommandText = "SELECT concat_ws(',', LastName, FirstName, MiddleName) as 'Applicant Name',EDate as 'Date of Examination', EScore as 'Examination Score', IStatus as 'Interview Status',IComment as 'Interview Comment' FROM tbl_applicant"

    Dim myadap As New MySqlDataAdapter(mycom)
    Dim mydt As New DataTable

    myadap.Fill(mydt)
    grdApplicantsAS.DataSource = mydt
    myadap.Dispose()
    mydt.Dispose()
End Sub
```

I came up with the list but i have no idea on how to insert buttons in every row with button 1 as Hire and button 2 as reject.. any help will do thanks

Comment: You need to add the datanames of your columns so when you fill the datagridview the data you pull back goes to their right field. You can add the two button columns in the designer...

Comment: where will i put the data names of my columns in the database???? @MrCoDeXeR

Comment: This can be done through the designer for the datagridview...click on the grid at the top will be a black arrow of sorts and click to edit columns in there you can specify columns ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mention in my comments above, you can do this in the designer or at runtime... Heres how to create one at runtime if you want. Do this before you set the DataSource if you want the columns at the beginning.

```
    Dim buttonColumn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
    buttonColumn.HeaderText = ""
    buttonColumn.Name = "Status Request"
    buttonColumn.Text = "Request Status"
    buttonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
    grdApplicantsAS.Columns.Add(buttonColumn)
```

Comment: i used your code, but everytime my LoadDataAS is performed the button is also repeatedly adding itself, and im using 2 buttons

Comment: You said you want to buttons add if im correct.. "i have no idea on how to insert buttons in every row with button 1 as Hire and button 2 as reject.. any help will do thanks" when do you NOT need them?

Comment: Also call grdApplicantAS.DataSource = nothing after you clear the textbox field. Then if they are not gone you can do, grdApplicantAS.Columns.Clear this will remove all columns. Your refreshing the grid anyways and its always good to clear everything out when and before you set it with new data.

Comment: P.S. check your other question about your query you asked I found out the query was formatted wrong, thanks.

Comment: i already solved that question..
by the way here is another question how can i make a if statement with the buttons you have taught me., i already made 2 buttons, the Hire and Regrets button, how can i create a if statement where if i press the Hire Button, i would go to another form,

Comment: If that question is solved can you mark it so others know please. Also yes to your question, can you make it another question so others can see as well please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100745/how-to-get-row-values-of-a-datagridview-and-pass-it-to-another-form-using-a-butt