# How to get row values of a datagridview and pass it to another form using a button in thesame row

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, datagridview

```
Public Sub LoadDataAS()
    grdApplicantsAS.DataSource = Nothing
    grdApplicantsAS.Columns.Clear()
    txtSearchBar1.Clear()
    mycom.Connection = cn
    mycom.CommandText = "SELECT concat_ws(',', LastName, FirstName, MiddleName) as 'Applicant Name',EDate as 'Date of Examination', EScore as 'Examination Score', IStatus as 'Interview Status',IComment as 'Interview Comment' FROM tbl_applicant"

    Dim myadap As New MySqlDataAdapter(mycom)
    Dim mydt As New DataTable

    myadap.Fill(mydt)
    grdApplicantsAS.DataSource = mydt
    Dim buttonColumn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
    buttonColumn.HeaderText = ""
    buttonColumn.Name = "Status Request"
    buttonColumn.Text = "Hire"
    buttonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
    grdApplicantsAS.Columns.Add(buttonColumn)
    Dim buttonColumn1 As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
    buttonColumn1.HeaderText = ""
    buttonColumn1.Name = "Status Request"
    buttonColumn1.Text = "Regrets"
    buttonColumn1.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
    grdApplicantsAS.Columns.Add(buttonColumn1)

    myadap.Dispose()
    mydt.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Every row of my datatable has two buttons hire and regrets respectively, a column of my data table contains phone numbers, i cant figure out, if how will i get the number of the same row where i clicked the button hire and pass it to another form.. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @Mr CoDeXeR Here it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you can use the `CellClick` event of your `DataGridView`, please see below.

```
  Private Sub grdApplicantsAS_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles grdApplicantsAS.CellClick
        Dim frm2 As Form2
        Try
            'First column button
            If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
               frm2 = New Form2(grdApplicantsAS.CurrentRow.Cells(YOUR NUMBER COLUMN).Value.ToString())
               frm2.ShowDialog()
            ElseIf e.ColumnIndex = 1
               'Do what you need here for the other button...
            End If             

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

**FORM 2 EXAMPLE**

```
 Public Class Form2
   Public Property EmployeeName As String

   'Pass your name in as the argument. Now Form 2 will have your name...
   Public Sub New(ByVal strEmployeeName As String)

     'Set your property of your employee name
     EmployeeName = strEmployeeName

   End Sub

 End Class
```

Comment: how to get the value of the specific cell then transfer it to another form?

Comment: @AkoCiDivine please see answer. Not sure what your other forms look like, but I provided a simple example. Where it say's "YOUR NUMBER COLUMN" you will put the columns name in that. Then this will be passed in the constructor.

Comment: I used the code but it says Too many arguments to public sub new

`frm2 = New Form(grdApplicantsAS.CurrentRow.Cells("Phone Number").Value.ToString())`

Comment: And you cant name your form "Form" its reserved.

Comment: Look at Form2 example above. Add another form to your project and put that code in it. Then in your other class you need to reference it...

Comment: I made this one but still it says that too many arguments
SMS = New SMS(grdApplicantsAS.CurrentRow.Cells("Phone Number").Value.ToString())

Comment: ill give you the setup of my application, if i press the button hire, it will go to my sms form but it must carry the phone number of the row where i press the hire button, the the phone number, would directly appear in the txtnumber textbox in my sms form

Comment: The way i showed u is just fine, your missing something. Give me a link with a download..

Comment: thanks by the way, i just declared a universal variable, then get the currentrow value to string, assign it then call it to the other form,,