# How do you carry variables from one form to another in a Windows Forms Application? (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, windows, forms

In the application I'm working on, I have several instances where I need to pass variables from one form to another. I've done it before using sessions in a web application, but I've never done it in a Windows Forms application.

For example, on one form I have a text box where the user enters the name of the opponent in a sporting event. I've done the basics - declared a `char` variable called `Opponent` and set it to catch whatever value gets entered into the textbox `Opponent = txtOpponent.Text`

Next I need to display whatever value that's stored in `Opponent` in a label on another form.

In my previous web application, I would have just used `Session.Add("Opponent", Me.txtOpponent.Text)` and then had `lblOpponent.Text = Session("Opponent").ToString` wherever my label was, but unfortunately it doesn't work like that.

So basically, I need to be able to initialize a variable on the first form of my application and have it be accessible to all the other forms.

Comment: you can pass this in as an argument when creating your new form...

Comment: You can reference this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100745/how-to-get-row-values-of-a-datagridview-and-pass-it-to-another-form-using-a-butt/27100904#27100904. I have already answered this before.

Comment: pass the data to the other form and let it set its own control(s)

Comment: Check this out: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html